# What's the difference between -> result=$(ls -l) (or) -> result=`ls -l`

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I'v run both commands and they both seem to do the same thing, is this true or is there something happening I'm not seeing?

These two appear to do the same thing:

```
result=$(ls -l)   
result=`ls -l`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out 
http://nixcraft.com/shell-scripting/13288-loop-input-backticks-vs-differences.html#post19804
for a nice explanation of this case.

Comment: huh ok, so looks like I was wise to manly use t=$(ls -l)
Thanks guys!

Comment: Good link, but I question their definition of "new" when saying that $() is a new syntax.  It is newer than backticks, but it's been around for a *long* time.

Answer (score 1):

The bash man page says the following, under Command Substitution.

> When the old-style backquote form of
>   substitution  is  used,  backslash
>   retains  its  literal  meaning except
>   when followed by $, `, or .  The
>   first backquote not preceded by a
>   backslash terminates the command
>   sub-stitution.  When using the
>   $(command) form, all characters
>   between the parentheses make up the
>   command; none are treated specially.
>
> Command substitutions may be nested. 
>   To nest when using the backquoted
>   form, escape the inner backquotes with
>   backslashes.

Online copies of the sh man page:

- [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)
- [osx](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sh.1.html)
- [free bsd](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&format=html)